# why do I have to pull my own branch from remote before push if I rebase modified master ontop of my banch locally?

Tags: git, git-workflow

why do I have to pull my own branch from remote  before push if I have rebased modified master ontop of my banch localy?

I was working on my development branch, meanwhile somebody updated master branch, so I rebased master branch on my development branch and got latest changes from master branch on remote.

Now when I do `git status` I get message saying My devbranch has divereged from origin/devbranch.

the git status suggest to git pull.
by doing so I am prompted to ammend the merge message.

after that I can push.
if i do not do the above and just do git push it gets rejected.
I was under impression that if I have changes in my development branch and I include changes from master then it should not restrict becuase HEAD of my development branch locally has moved, and upstream is following my branch locally !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so I rebased master branch on my development branch and got latest changes from master branch on remote.

This makes no sense, and you normally would not rebase *master* on some feature branch.  What I think you actually did is the reverse, namely to rebase your development branch on `master` to bring in the latest changes.

When you completed the rebase, you rewrote the history of your development branch.  What this effectively does is to create a situation where your local development branch is now diverging from the remote version.  The typical way to remedy this is to just force push:

```
git push --force origin development
```

This will overwrite the remote development branch with the rebased version.

Comment: so instead of rebase master ontop of my feature branch, should i do `git fetch origin master` and then `git pull` then merge master on my development branch ?

Comment: You seem very confused about what is going on/what to do.  If you want to bring the latest changes from `master` into your development branch, you can either merge `master` into dev, or you can `git rebase origin/master` on your dev branch.  If the latter, then you would probably have to force push dev to the remote.

Comment: my knowledge says force push is never a good idea , but I wonder when merge is simplest strategy why do people so inclined to rebase. I am just doing this for someone else.

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz You're right, in general force push is not a good idea, but nothing in Git is inherently evil.  Force pushing a feature branch after rebasing on master is one of the totally legitimate reasons to use it.  Actually, it is basically the _only_ option you have at that point, if you want to keep using that rebased feature branch.